# Get cue in HTML5 track element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

In testing out the HTML5 track element, the cue comes up null. The TextTrackList and track element appear to load. Also, I am aware that VTT files aren't accessible locally, and I'm testing on a server. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

This is my Javascript:

```
        var audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
        var textTracks = audioElement.textTracks;
        var textTrack = textTracks[0];
        var ques = textTrack.cues;
        var que = ques[0];
        console.log(que);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
        <audio src="Audio Files/Q_firefox.ogg" controls>
        <track src="cues.vtt"></track>
        </audio>
```

Comment: just in case you are trying with firefox....
do you know that the track element is not currently supported in firefox?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tested in Chrome as well with the same result.

Comment: I have not been able to make the audio player display text (chrome browser on linux).

it does work however if you put the ogg file in an `<video>` tag instead of an `<audio>` tag.
so, it seems that _at least my audio player_ has currently no support for subtitles/captions etc.

Answer (score 2):

The cue value changes as the track plays so you need to listen for the value to change and run your function each time the text changes. Try this example based on your question:

```js
var audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
var textTrack = audioElement.textTracks[0];

// When cue value changes run your code
textTrack.oncuechange = function(e) {
  var cue = this.activeCues[0];
  if(cue){
    console.log(cue.text);
  }
}
```

```html
<audio src="http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/Google_Developer_Stories.webm" controls>
  <track src="http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/video-subtitles-en.vtt" default>
</audio>
```

Also note no need to close HTML track tag.

Comment: Thanks! This saved a lot of my time.... Any idea how I can obtain the whole subtitle before the audio is played? I need to highlight the current subtitle when the audio is played.